# How to setup GitLab CE CI to user docker images for runners

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've now tried for several days to get a runner working on a docker container. I have a Debian running system with GitLab, gitlab-runner and docker installed. I want to use docker as a container for my runners, because shell executors are installing all things on my CI maschine...

What I have done until now: I installed docker like it is described in the GitLab CE docs and run this command:

```
gitlab-runner register -n \
  --url DOMAIN \
  --registration-token TOKEN \
  --executor docker \
  --description "docker-builder" \
  --docker-image "gliderlabs/alpine" \
  --docker-privileged
```

then I created a test repo to look if it is working, with this .gitlab-ci-yml

```
variables:
  # GIT_STRATEGY: fetch # re-uses the project workspace
  GIT_CHECKOUT: "false" # don't checkout the working copy to a revision related to the CI pipeline
  GIT_DEPTH: "3"

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  - ls -la

# ======================= Jobs=======================
# Teporaly disable jobs by adding a . (dot) before the job name

ftp-upload:
  stage: deploy
  # environment: Production
  except: 
    - testing
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ls -la
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$PASSWORD
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r . $USERNAME@$HOST:/Test
  only:
    - master

# ===================== ./Jobs ======================
```

but I get an error in the GitLab CI console:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.1.0 (081978aa)
  on docker-builder 5ce3c211
Using Docker executor with image gliderlabs/alpine ...
Pulling docker image gliderlabs/alpine ...
Using docker image sha256:74a78e860d7b39aa694197a70d4467019b611b80c21d886fcd1bfc04d2e767d4 for gliderlabs/alpine ...
Running on runner-5ce3c211-project-3-concurrent-0 via srvvgit001...
Cloning repository for master with git depth set to 3...
Cloning into '/builds/additive/test'...
Skipping Git checkout
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
/bin/sh: eval: line 64: apt-get: not found
$ apt-get update
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I don't know much about those docker containers but them seems good for reuse without modifying my CI system. It looks here that it is installing another alpine image/container, but have I not said GitLab runner to use an existing one?

Hopefully, there is someone that can easier explain to me how this works... I really have tried anything google gave me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker image you are using is a Alpine image, which is a minimal Linux distribution.
Alpine Linux is not using `apt` for package management but `apk`.

The problem is in your `.gitlab-ci-yml`'s `before_script` section where you are trying to run `apt`.

To solve your issue, replace the use of `apt` by `apk`:

```
before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add sshpass
...
```

Read more about the Alpine Linux package management [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management).

Comment: Ahh, I did not know that... Thanks!

Comment: But is it right that gitlab runner is creating a new image every time? I see that it is pulling gliderlabs/alpine every time. I thought I had it installed and one installation would work.

Comment: The GitLab runner is instructing Docker to download your Docker image once, and reuse the downloaded image as long there isn't a newer version of the specified image tag. The downloaded images are stored in the Docker local image registry on your runners machine. You can list all installed images on your Docker machine using `docker images --all`. The scripts you are executing from your `.gitlab-ci-yml` are run each time your repository has changes, in your case if you push to master.

Comment: "Pulling docker image gliderlabs/alpine ..." Does not mean that docker is downloading a new image. It means that Docker is acquiring the image, not necessarily from upstream, as it checks your local cache for the image first. If the image can't be found in your cache, Docker will download the image for you.

Comment: mhm okay I understand. But why do I get this error?
The container name "/runner-5ce3c211-project-3-concurrent-0-predefined-0" is already in use by container "ae04057d81dcfce6fbb28091336151cb1660f32b3dbbdc21ae06d778c7c7d2e9". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name. (executor_docker.go:922:0s)

Comment: I've just set up another task and it looks like it tries to execute them both on the same image

Comment: At this point, you should consider asking a new question on StackOverflow as it is out of the scope of the initial question. It seems like a different problem, not regarding the `.gitlab-ci-yml` but rather your runner or Docker configuration.